# Remote Desktop disconnect session hotkey

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

I have been searching for a while on how I might do this. I am connected to a Windows Server 2003 machine from a Windows 7 machine using Remote Desktop. I would like a way to disconnect the active session with a hotkey. I am running Remote Desktop in fullscreen mode.

**Details**

```
Remote Desktop Connection

Shell Version 6.3.9600
Control Version 6.3.960
2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved

Network Level Authentication supported.
Remote Desktop Protocol 8.1 supported.
```

I have also tried using the <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>home</kbd> key combo and the <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> suggested [with this question](https://superuser.com/a/296679/348258), however this closes the title bar causing me to need to disconnect and reconnect to get the title bar back. If I could use a hotkey, I would no longer need the title bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote Desktop doesn't have such a hotkey due to the various OS's you can connect to, which may have different hotkeys for different functionality. What I could recommend is using the <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> keys. This should open up the shut down menu. From there you should be able to navigate to the disconnect option using the arrow keys and hit enter to disconnect and close the connection.

Comment: But I wish there was a better way of doing this. You could accidently logoff or worse, shutdown the remote machine.

Comment: This would probably be your best bet: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/41499/scripting-how-to-disconnect-remote-desktop-sessions). Then you would have to figure out how to search for your username to grab the correct ID and disconnect that ID. Not to mention setting up a "hot key" to execute the batch job. Good luck!